# Thymeleaf template not loading when Controller is requested

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectController {
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String displayProjectForm() {
        return "new-project";
    }
}
```

When I launch the Spring Boot and navigate to localhost:8080/projects/new

This is a very simple starter project. It just has 1 controller and 1 html file under /resources/templates

called new-project.html

[image: Error]

the html file looks like this

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/projects/save" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
            <select>
                <option th:value="NOTSTARTED"> Not Started</option>
                <option th:value="INPROGRESS"> In Progress</option>
                <option th:value="COMPLETED"> Completed</option>
            </select>
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Project Description"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Create Project</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

POM  File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.oneorangetree.pma</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-management</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What url are you hitting? This works for me when I test it in spring boot accessing `http://localhost:8080/projects/new`.

Comment: Actually, you say your template is named `new-projects.html` but you have `return "new-project";` -- you are missing an `s` here.

Comment: I added the 's' in the StackoverFlow but the actual file is called 'new-project.html'. I am using Visual Studio Code. I am not really sure what is causing the issue here. What IDE did you use?

Comment: This should work... Did you set a context path (`server.servlet.context-path`) ?

Comment: I was using Netbeans 8.2 lol... but the project was a newish spring boot project I generated.  My template was in `src/main/resources/templates/new-projects.html`

Comment: @DirkDeyne please explain a bit more...

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce: https://imgur.com/a/1oMHSRK

Comment: `<form action="/projects/save" method="POST">` works "under circumstances", but better: [thymeleaf URL Syntax!](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Comment: @xerx593 seems like it only happens in VS Code. I downloaded IntelliJ and it worked without any problems. Has anyone tried in VS Code?